# how to connect Tango to external PCB?

Tags: google-project-tango

for example I would like to use Tango as the core of a robot, and let it drive some motors. I need to export some drive signals. what is the recommended hardware interface? USB ?

Thanks
Yang

Comment: Project Tango has a bluetooth controller, USB and USB Host which can be used in combination to send or receive signals to external hardware interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most of android interfaces should work on Tango tablets as well, if you have a interface that works on any other android device, you should be able to pass Tango data through that interface as well. You might need to write a program that posting the Tango data to the interface, that part could be done using either [C](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/index) or [Java](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/) API provided by Project Tango.